# A possible way for generic type arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Does creating an array of generic objects, in this fashion, has any downsides or performance issues?

`QueryObjects instances[] = (QueryObjects<String,String,String>[]) new Object[10];`

**Edit:** I was even thinking if I could instead rely on this:-

`QueryObjects instances[] = new QueryObjects[10];`

The primary reason for this being, I do *not want* to  fix the generic to `<String,String,String>` because sometimes it can also be like `<Integer,Integer,Integer>` for some elements of array. So I would like to give it as a runtime choice. Since this is mostly for application's internal work and not for any client side input, perhaps I should not be facing the danger of wrong inputs.

Comment: You don't accomplish anything with the cast.  No type checking will be performed to make sure it's a `<String, String, String>`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan ! I just added some more info to my question.. please have a short look to it..

Answer (score 2):

Creating it in this way does have a downside: you now have what is really an array of any kind of `Object` disguised as an array of `QueryObjects`. If someone else has a reference to the same array (and know that it is an `Object[]`), they could put some `Object` into it, e.g. a `String`, and then the program will throw a `ClassCastException` when you try to access that `String` through your reference to the array. Solution: create it like this:

```
QueryObjects<String, String, String> instances[] = new QueryObjects[10];
```

Comment: -1 Can't do either of these in Java.  Both give you a compile error: `Cannot create a generic array of QueryObjects<String, String, String>`

Comment: @Jonathon My bad - I've been programming too much C#. At any rate, it was sloppy to provide untested code; sorry and thanks for pointing it out. My updated solution _is_ tested... (My argument about `ClassCastException` is still correct, though; that I _did_ test...)

Comment: Vote reversed.  That will work, assuming you don't mind unchecked warnings.  Java generics are pretty bad :(

Comment: @Jonathon Agreed. I'll take an "unchecked conversion" warning over a possible `ClassCastException` any day, though... ;-) (Of course, you always risk that exception when using generics in Java, but at least you need to work harder to produce it...)

Answer (score 2):

Your code will generate a `ClassCastException` at run time.

You should create an array of type `QueryObjects[]` and cast it to `QueryObjects<String, String, String>[]`, or in the future, if you need to create an array of a variable type (e.g., `T[]`), use reflection: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 2):

the "righteous" way is

```
QueryObjects<?,?,?>[] instances = new QueryObjects<?,?,?>[10];
```

the raw way is just fine:

```
QueryObjects[] instances = new QueryObjects[10];
```

notice the type declaration:

```
Type[] var
```

not

```
Type var[]
```

I don't care why Java allows the 2nd syntax, it still doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It begs the question "If you're using generics, why use an array instead of an a typed structure?"

Instead of trying to achieve `QueryObjects[]` and doing it poorly, why not create a type for it? Then you can add whatever methods you want. Yay object orientation!

```
class QuerySet<O extends QueryObjects<A,B,C>> {
    O[] objects;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I might have a syntax error on the `<O extends QO<A,B,C>>`. I don't have the time to test it for syntactical accuracy at the moment.

Comment: Thanks glocoder! I just tried it out..thid syntax seems to work 
`class QuerySet<O extends QueryObjects> {`
    `O[] object;`
`}`

Can this fit with my needs that I mentioned in the edits.. like some elements of this array could be <String,String,String> whereas other elements could be like <Integer,Integer,Integer>.

Comment: If the behavior is the same, then yes, it can. If the behavior is different depending on Integer or String, you shouldn't use a generic. Think about what generic means!